# Algo Coding interview: arbitrage from FX matrix

Tags: algorithm

Here is an Algo Coding interview question:

> Suppose n*n matrix F is the FX rates matrix F[i][j] = f, which means 1 unit Ccyi = f units Ccyj. What's the maximal arbitrage based on this matrix? Note that F[i][i]=1 and F[i][j]*F[j][i] is not neccesary 1. For example 1 EUR = 2 USD, 1 USD = 0.6 EUR, then EUR->USD->EUR: 1 EUR => 2 USD => 1.2 EUR, there is an arbitrage.

The question is not complete, to avoid infinity times of exchange, I guess we should fix the exchange times k and start Ccy and end Ccy should be same. e.g. k=3, Ccy1->Ccy2->Ccy3->Ccy1. I am not sure if it is a reasonable assumption.

**EDIT:**

From hint here:

https://anilpai.medium.com/currency-arbitrage-using-bellman-ford-algorithm-8938dcea56ea

The problem is just to find the maximal non-repeat circle. But above link uses Bellman Ford Algorithm to only find the existence of arbitrage opportunity (negative cost circle) but not the largest one.

Comment: Something like [this](https://anilpai.medium.com/currency-arbitrage-using-bellman-ford-algorithm-8938dcea56ea)?

Comment: @גלעדברקן above  discussion only find the existence of arbitrage but not the maximal one.

Comment: Unfortunately the non-repeat criterion makes this NP-hard by reduction from Hamilton cycle.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Could I understand that this question is purely not a easy algo coding test?

Comment: I suppose you could find the maximum mean cycle efficiently, which would give you the best log profit *per trade*. But in general I think you'd be more than fine if you know to take logs and run Bellman–Ford.